# Facing issue while using #yammer api

Tags: yammer

I have implemented yammer authentication. but it seems there is an bug with yammer api. When i am trying to get access token with client_id, client_secret and code it gives following error message

Oops!
The page you were looking for could not be found.

## yammer please let me know is there any issue.

Thanks,
Prashant Kumar Pal

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, it seems that Yammer is changing their API's without communication, amateurs :S

Anyway the solution is to use a POST request instead of a GET for the access_token API:

These instructions are still correct except the fact you cannot do that using browser GET requests anymore:
https://developer.yammer.com/oauth2-quickstart/

Here's what I changed in my code, note that one line was changed from GET to POST:

```cs
    private void GetBearerToken(string userCode)
    {
        string formatUri = string.Format("https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token.json?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&code={2}", this.clientId, this.clientSecret, userCode);
        Uri yammerUri = new Uri(formatUri);

        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(yammerUri);
        webRequest.Method = "POST"; // changed line

        using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                var s = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.ASCII);
                dynamic accessTokenResponse = Json.Decode(s.ReadToEnd());
                this.Token = accessTokenResponse.access_token.token;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with Yammer yesterday and my code magically stopped working as well. Right now I am using this page to troubleshoot:

https://developer.yammer.com/oauth2-quickstart/

And even the steps there are giving me a 404! Unfortunately they do not seem to have a support email address :(

Please post back when you have an update...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was a known issue. A fix has been deployed -  http://status.yammer.com/2014/10/15/resolved-3rd-party-application-authorization-10152014-1114-pdt/